# how to use 2 parameter route get node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes, get

How to use 2 parameter in 1 route (get) this is my code

```
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
        Result.find(function(error, results){
        if (error) console.log(error)

        response.render('index', {results:results})
      })
    })

router.get('/', function (request, response) {
        Result.count({stuff:"book"}, function(error, count){
        if(error) console.log(error)

        response.render('index', {count})
      })
    })
```

I have tried to combine to be like this but i got an error

```
router.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
        Result.find(function(error, results){
        if (error) console.log(error)

        response.render('index', {results:results})
      }),
        Result.count( {stuff:"book"}, function(error, count){
        if(error) console.log(error)

        response.render('index', {count})
      })
    })
```

#note :
if I use one of them is running perfectly (nothing error), but I need 2 parameter..

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do here. You can only respond to a request once and so you should decide which of these two responses you want. Do you want to send both the count and results in one response? If so, nest the callbacks (not great, but works for starters), then add both results and count to the view you're rendering, call `response.render` once. It's a good idea to respond with an error status if you have an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send both pieces of data to your template, you will have to collect both pieces of data in one route handler and then call `res.render()` once with both pieces of data.

You only get to send one response for an incoming request so if you want to render the template with multiple pieces of data, then you collect all that data and call `res.render()` once, passing it all the data it needs and your template should be configured to expect all the data to be passed to it at once:

```
// use database callbacks and nest the two calls
router.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    Result.find(function(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            response.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        Result.count({ stuff: "book" }, function(error, count) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                response.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }
            response.render('index', { count, results });
        });
    });
});
```

Or, using the promise interface on your database (which I presume it has):

```
// using Promises and Promise.all() to run both queries in parallel
router.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    Promise.all([Result.find(), Result.count({ stuff: "book" })]).then(([results, count]) => {
        response.render('index', { count, results });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(error);
        response.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```